# Put informations into a list

Tags: c, list, variables

I'm programming in C language...
I'm having a problem

I have this input:
LIS MAD 4 TP001 TP002 TP003 TP004

and what I need to do is to scan all of the information and put it in a list...

The thing is, the number of TP is variable, it can go from 1 to 1000...

Please help me... I have no ideia how to do this..

Maybe a cycle for will help... I don't know.

My problem remains with the variable number of TP's. The rest, I know...

Thanks!!

Comment: In the example does the `4` indicate four `TPs`?

Comment: -1 for not putting the requirements IN YOUR QUESTION.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain what you are doing.
Where is this input?

- Is it arguments to you program? - So
  You simply need to loop through the
  arguments
- Or input into the console? -Use scanf

Trying reading:

- http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf

Comment: my input is a big list of different lines like the ones I said before. The thing is, from line to line, the number of TP's can change. I'm using scanf, but how do I tell him to use scanf as long as there is something to scan

Comment: also, the number after the LIS and MAD changes according to the number of TP's

Comment: @Fred: you can use `fgets()` to read a full line, then `sscanf()` little by little.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment for [gskspurs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808549/put-informations-into-a-list/5808640#5808640), it seems you have a variable number of space-delimited strings on many lines?

You need to start by using [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to get one line, and then use either [`sscanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) to get each word one at a time, until the end of the string (i.e., the end of the line).

In a further comment, you mentioned that the token after LIS/MAD describes how many words follow it. Okay, so your goal is to do the following:

1. Read a line using `fgets`.
2. Read the "LIS" and "MAD" words, and do what you need to do with them (or ignore them). (You can use `sscanf`)
3. Use `sscanf` to read into an integer, the number of words to follow. (Let's call this `n` for this discussion.)
4. Use [`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to allocate an array of strings (type `char **`), the number of elements being `n`.
5. Read a word and store it into the array of strings, `n` times.

Let me know if you need clarification.

---

Here's a quick sample:

```
#define LINE_SIZE 1024

char line[LINE_SIZE];     /* Unfortunately you do need to specify a maximum line size. */

while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, stdin) != NULL)
{
    /* If we're here, a line was read into the "line" variable. We assume the entire line fits. */

    char lis_string[4];
    char mad_string[4];
    int num_words;
    int offset;

    char **word_array;

    sscanf(line, "%s %s %d %n", lis_string, mad_string, &num_words, &offset);

    /* Allocate memory for num_words words */
    word_array = malloc(sizeof(*word_array) * num_words);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_words; ++i)
    {
        int chars_read;

        /* Allocate space for each word. Assume maximum word length */
        word_array[i] = malloc(sizeof(*word_array[i]) * 16);

        sscanf(line + offset, "%s %n", num_words[i], &chars_read);
        offset += temp;
    }

    /* Do something with the words we just got, maybe print them or add them to a file */
    do_something_with_words(lis_string, mad_string, num_words, word_array);

    /* At the end of this loop, lis_string/mad_string/num_words are out of scope, and
       will be overwritten in next loop iteration. We need to free up the word_array
       to make sure no memory is leaked. */

    for (i = 0; i < num_words; ++i)
    {
        free(word_array[i]);
    }
    free(word_array);
}
```

Comment: Thats seems like a great solution! Thanks! The only thins is that I don't know how to use `fgets()`, about `sscanf()` does it store what it scans into a variable?

Comment: If you know how to use `scanf`, `sscanf` words just like it except that you supply a string to be scanned as your first argument.

Comment: If I understood correctly, fgets reads a whole line from a file.. But my file of input has more than one line, and I only want to read the ones started with a p
fo example: p LIS MAD 4 TP001 TP002 TP003 TP004

Comment: @Fred Carvalho: Really? Put ALL your requirements in your question in the future... Please. Stop changing the requirements on us.

Comment: I'm really sorry... I had forgotten about that detail

Comment: It's okay... Just go ahead and edit your question, with the exact requirements this time, and then I can make a fresh start on an answer. Okay? :-)